# How to do Dynamic page navigation in xamarin forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am working on xamarin.forms. Where I need to do navigation based on menu clicked. It's a dynamic menu, order of menus might change or based on the user logged in the menus will be changing. What I need to do is I will get from API to which page I should navigate, I need to pass that page name dynamically. Is it possible or not? If yes please help me out.

```
var dynamicpage = "MenuPage()";
new NavigationPage (new dynamicpage );// Like this
```

Comment: Dynamic initialization can work but not like this, since you said you have menu items and on click of them you want to load a certain page tells me you have a set number of pages, Add all the relevant code and maybe we can find a way

Comment: In code behind your page inside of constructor you can create all of elements inside a master grid and adding the children elements.
Keep Calm!! this can work but is not the best way to build a screen dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

It is much easier with [Shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/), you can define your pages based on your hierarchical design inside `<Shell>` thanks to `Route`. Also you may benefit from [efficient page loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/tabs#efficient-page-loading) by using `DataTemplate` which will load the page only when required (navigated to).

Regarding [navigation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/navigation#routes) you can explicitly navigate from code behind to any page by specifying the route of that page that you have already registered when you defined your `<Shell>` or in the code behind.

If you encounter the exception

> System.ArgumentException: 'unable to figure out route for: //RegisterPage Parameter name: uri'

Then you probably didn't register the route before it got invoked or you made a typo on the route. You can refer to [Bug? System.ArgumentException: 'unable to figure out route for:](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65002712)

For more details you can always check the linked Microsoft official documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [`Activator.CreateInstance()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.activator.createinstance?view=net-5.0)?

```
var pageType = typeof(MenuPage);
var navPage = new NavigationPage((Page)Activator.CreateInstance(pageType));
```