# Bug? System.ArgumentException: 'unable to figure out route for:

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.shell

Error

> System.ArgumentException: 'unable to figure out route for:
> //RegisterPage Parameter name: uri' System.ArgumentException: 'unable
> to figure out route for: //LogoPage Parameter name: uri'

What is wrong? It cant figure out the route...?

XAML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="MyApp.Views.WelcomePage"
             Shell.NavBarIsVisible="False">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout Padding="10,0,10,0" VerticalOptions="Center">
            <Button VerticalOptions="Center" Text="Register" Command="{Binding RegisterCommand}"/>
            <Button VerticalOptions="Center" Text="Login" Command="{Binding LoginCommand}"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Code behind

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class WelcomePage : ContentPage
{
    public WelcomePage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.BindingContext = new WelcomeViewModel();
    }
}
```

WelcomeViewModel.cs

```
public Command RegisterCommand { get; }
public Command LoginCommand { get; }

public WelcomeViewModel()
{
    RegisterCommand = new Command(OnRegisterClicked);
    LoginCommand = new Command(OnLoginClicked);
}

private async void OnRegisterClicked(object obj)
{
    await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//{nameof(RegisterPage)}");
}

private async void OnLoginClicked(object obj)
{
    await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//{nameof(LoginPage)}");
}
```

Comment: How you are consuming `LoginPage` and `RegisterPage` in your main page `<Shell>` ? in other words what is the hierarchy/structure of your pages? Have you register your pages with `Route`?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Your need to register a route for each page you are willing to navigate into it using `Shell.Current.GoToAsync()`, with this way you can also clarify your pages hierarchy:

```
    <FlyoutItem FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsMultipleItems">

        <ShellContent Title="RegisterPage"
                      Route="RegisterPage"
                      ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:RegisterPage}"/>

        <ShellContent Title="LoginPage"
                      Route="LoginPage"
                      ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:LoginPage}"/>

        <ShellContent Title="Page3"
                      ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Page3}"/>

    </FlyoutItem>
```

You can also register the route using `Routing.RegisterRoute()` in the code if you prefer, as long as it runs before a route is invoked:
`Routing.RegisterRoute("//Page3", typeof(Page3));`

#### Microsoft Documentation

For more details: [Shell Navigation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/navigation#routes)

Comment: This exception is also thrown when you try to navigate to a flyoutitem or menuitem which has IsVisible="false" (Xamarin.Forms 4.8.0.1451)

Comment: @this.myself i will test it, have you tried it with 5.0.0 pre version if it is fixed or now? Or if an isuue has been aleardy filled for it?

Comment: no, I did not test with 5.0 pre and I didn't look up if there is an issue cause I found a solution for my problem

Comment: I can confirm that when I updated Xamarin.Forms to `5.0.0.2337` the "exception is also thrown when you try to navigate to a flyoutitem or menuitem which has `IsVisible="false"`". Indeed there is/was an Issue: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/12428

Comment: And here is the doc link that explains the "new" way as of 5.0 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/flyout#flyoutitem-visibility
TLDR: FlyoutItem.FlyoutItemIsVisible="False" not FlyoutItem.IsVisible="False" (FlyoutItem.IsVisible is inherited from the BaseShellItem but there is no description about it in the docs currently)

Answer (score 5):

For my problem, I registered routes behind of ShellPage, It took a while to figure out and add new route to get work.
I am not sure it is the best way to register routes in AppShell.cs

```
public partial class AppShell : Shell
{
    public AppShell()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(PartPage), typeof(PartPage)); 
        Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(DetailPage), typeof(DetailPage));
        Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(PersonPage), typeof(PersonPage));
    }
}
```

Comment: I actually prefer this method, as it's concise and doesn't rely on magic strings.