# Correct place to register shell page routing?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.shell

Where is the correct place to register page route (that is not visible on the flyout menu)?

When page is not visible on the flyout menu, I add it to `OnStart` method via App.xaml.cs

```
protected override void OnStart()
{
    Routing.RegisterRoute("RegisterPage", typeof(RegisterPage));
    Routing.RegisterRoute("LoginPage", typeof(LoginPage));
}
```

When page is visible on the flyout menu, I add page routing like this

```
<FlyoutItem Title="Home" Icon="icon_home.png">
    <ShellContent Route="HomePage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:HomePage}" />
</FlyoutItem>
```

Comment: From [Shell.Navigation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/navigation#register-page-routes) "In the Shell subclass constructor, or any other location that runs before a route is invoked, additional routes can be explicitly registered for any pages that aren't represented in the Shell visual hierarchy:"

Comment: what would happen if you accidently register a page twice?

Comment: I believe nothing even with two different routes, but this is not included in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should register the route before use it.

From the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/navigation#register-page-routes):

> In the Shell subclass constructor, or any other location that runs
> before a route is invoked, additional routes can be explicitly
> registered for any pages that aren't represented in the Shell visual
> hierarchy

Answer (score 0):

As mentionned in my [comment yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65004161/xamarin-shell-correct-place-to-register-page-routing/65018308#comment114923078_65004161)
From [Shell.Navigation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/navigation#register-page-routes):

> "In the Shell subclass constructor, or any other location that runs before a route is invoked, additional routes can be explicitly registered for any pages that aren't represented in the Shell visual hierarchy:"

So at the end it depends on personal choice **as long as it is registered before it is being invoked**.

#### Related question

[Bug? System.ArgumentException: 'unable to figure out route for:](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65002712/5228202)